# Output clock of the LPC1768?

Tags: clock, pinout, lpc, nxp, lpc1768

I am using NXP's [LPC1768](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/) development board and I came across the [User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf) for this part and page 67/849 section 4.10 descusses the External Clock Output. I couldn't figure out which pin out of the 40 pinouts on the board is this clock out sitting on. By Googling around, I found this code that is supposed to output 10MHz:

```
/* clkout of 10mhz on 1.27 */
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL3 &=~(3<<22);
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL3 |= (1<<22);
LPC_SC->CLKOUTCFG = (1<<8)|(14<<4); //enable and divide by 12
```

But again, I am not sure which of the board pins this clock is coming out from? Or do I have to solder a connection to somewhere on the board?

**UPDATE**
I have tested the code that `Nils Pipenbrinck` provided. It works. But I am not sure if there are limitations on that clock output and its accuracy. Here are screenshots for frequencies 10MHz, 5MHz, 1MHz: - it seems to degrade as you we go higher. Any input on how to improve the signal's shape and accuracy?

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Zuofus answer I'd just thought I post the code to setup timer2 for this duty. I use it to clock a CPLD at various frequencies, and it works like a charm.

```
// flexible frequency synthesizer for the LPC1768 mbed board.
// this uses the TIM2 timer in countdown mode, toggling
// the MAT2.0 pin on each event (DIP-8 in the prototype board)

// the frequency will always be a bit off for high clock-rates because
// only integer divisions of the main clock are possible. 

void StartFreqSynth (uint32_t freqHz)
/////////////////////////////////////
{
  // ------------------------
  // Enable Power for Timer2:
  // ------------------------
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1<<22);

  // -----------------------------------
  // Disable counter and hold in reset:
  // -----------------------------------
  LPC_TIM2->TCR = 2;       // rest counter

  // -------------------------------------------
  // Set Clock source for Timer2 (bit 12 and 13)
  // we pick full system clock, divider 2,4,8
  // are also available
  // -------------------------------------------
  LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 = (LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 & ~(3<<12)) | (1<<12);

  // ----------------------------------
  // Use normal Timer mode, no capture
  // ---------------------------------- 
  LPC_TIM2->CTCR = 0;

  // -----------------------------------------------
  // Match on MR0 = TC. Reset counter, no interrupts
  // -----------------------------------------------
  LPC_TIM2->MCR = 2;     

  // ------------------------------------------------
  // set pin function for pin DIP_8 (P0.6) to MAT2.0
  // ------------------------------------------------
  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= 3<<12;

  // ----------------------------------
  // toggle pin MAT2.0 (DIP_8) on match
  // ----------------------------------
  LPC_TIM2->EMR  = 1 | (3<<4);

  // -----------------------------------
  // Set clock divider and match value
  // this determines the final frequency
  // -----------------------------------  
  LPC_TIM2->PR   = 0; // set prescaler to full speed.

  // since we toggle the pin, the generated frequency is half
  // as fast as a cycle, so we have to run the timer twice as
  // fast to compensate:
  LPC_TIM2->MR0  = CORE_FREQ / (freqHz*2);  // match value

  // start counter
  LPC_TIM2->TCR  = 1;       
}



void StopFreqSynth()
////////////////////
{
  // check if timer2 is powered:
  if (LPC_SC->PCONP & (1<<22))
  {
    // never generate interrupts:
    LPC_TIM2->MCR = 0;

    // put timer2 in reset, stop timer.
    LPC_TIM2->TCR = 2; 

    // disable peripheral power
    LPC_SC->PCONP &= ~(1<<22);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I will try it out soon after I will solder a wire out. Wanted to ask - is it possible to use the PWM pins as a clock?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul Yes, they perfectly work as a lower speed clock. I use exactly the above code to clock a CollRunner2 CPLD at 12Mhz. Works like a charm, even on breadboard.

Comment: So I still have to solder a wire out? Not sure which of the oscillators is the right one, and the pinout on the ethernet and uC itself are too small. How did you break out the clock pin?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul If you use the code above you'll get your clock at the pin P8, no soldering required.

Comment: Thanks. What is "CORE_FREQ" I get an error for that variable.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul You can define it as 96000000 (aka 96Mhz). It's the main processor speed.

Comment: I have tested the code, with Core Frequency of 96MHz and it works. But the output frequency (with respect to GND pin) is not so great. I have attached screenshots in the Question - and it shows that the frequency is not really accurate, and the clock shape degrades as we go higher. Are there limits on the frequency? I need 10MHz.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul my highest frequency is 5.6Mhz, and I have no problems reaching that. How is your setup looking? Any long leads? Maybe the scope probe is loading the pin?

Comment: No long leads. It was not loaded at all. Just the Tektronix probe between Pin 8 and GND. You can see that @ 1MHz it is fine and 5 it starts to get crappier. What is the rise/drop time for this?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [schematic](https://developer.mbed.org/media/uploads/chris/mbed-005.1.pdf), the pin you are using for CLKOUT is P1.27, which is used for the Ethernet clock enable (ETH_OSC_EN). This is pin 43 on the LPC1768 chip and goes to the enable pin on the Ethernet oscillator (ASE-50-C-T). It does not appear to be broken out anywhere else on the board, so you will have to solder a wire to it at one of those two points on the board.

If you need to generate an external clock without using CLKOUT and without wasting CPU cycles, you can use one of the match outputs. Set the match register to some small value (which will be your clock divider from your PCLK) and enable the corresponding counter/match register. Set it to reset the counter and toggle the output on a timer match event.

Comment: That's what I do to generate flexible clock output. Works like a charm.

Comment: Is CLKOUT broken anywhere on the LPC1768 board? If it is, how can CLKOUT be used?

Comment: The whole idea behind using the match register is to avoid having to solder to CLKOUT. Nils' answer below uses MAT2.0, which is already connected to pin 8 on the MBED.